# Confidence intervals for glmmTMB negative binomial model

Tags: r, lme4, emmeans

I am trying to calculate 95% confidence intervals for model estimates in `glmmTMB` (family: nbinom1).

I am able to do this using a `glmer.nb` model and `emmeans`, using `type = "response"` to back-transform the estimates and confidence intervals.

```
model = glmer.nb (response ~ p1 + p2 + (1|block))
emmeans(model, ~ p1 + p2, type = "response")
```

I think the similar function in `glmmTMB` is `confint(model)` , but it does not back-transform the estimates.

Can anyone help me make this work using a `glmmTMB` model, in the way it works for `glmer`?

Answer (score 1):

This is an apples-versus-oranges situation.

The `emmeans` call computes predictions from the model at each combination of `p1` and `p2`. Those can be back-transformed.

However, `confint(model)` asks for inferences on the regression coefficients. Those coefficients are in essence slopes. They are not on the log scale like the EMMs are, and they cannot be back-transformed.

Answer (score 1):

`emmeans()` *should* also work for **glmmTMB** models. For me, it works, and CI are also back-transformed (*from* log scale):

```r
library(glmmTMB)
data(Salamanders)

m <- glmmTMB(
  count ~ spp + mined + (1 | site),
  ziformula = ~ spp + mined,
  family = truncated_poisson,
  data = Salamanders
)

emmeans::emmeans(m, "spp", type = "response")
#>  spp    rate    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
#>  GP    1.553 0.223 627    1.171     2.06
#>  PR    0.922 0.251 627    0.540     1.57
#>  DM    1.944 0.250 627    1.511     2.50
#>  EC-A  1.277 0.246 627    0.875     1.86
#>  EC-L  2.965 0.337 627    2.372     3.71
#>  DES-L 2.844 0.321 627    2.280     3.55
#>  DF    1.626 0.222 627    1.244     2.13
#> 
#> Results are averaged over the levels of: mined 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95 
#> Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

In case you need predicted values (*and* confidence intervals) for mixed models with *zero-inflation*, the computation is a bit more complicated, but implemented in the [ggeffects-package](http://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects). You can find more details [in this vignette](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/introduction_randomeffects.html).

By default, both `predict()` and `emmeans()` do not return the most appropriate confidence intervals, as proposed by Brooks et al. (see https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2017/RJ-2017-066/RJ-2017-066.pdf, appendix).

See examples here:

```r
library(glmmTMB)
data(Salamanders)

m <- glmmTMB(
  count ~ spp + mined + (1 | site),
  ziformula = ~ spp + mined,
  family = truncated_poisson,
  data = Salamanders
)

# emmeans, not taking zero-inflation component into account
emmeans::emmeans(m, "spp", type = "response")
#>  spp    rate    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
#>  GP    1.553 0.223 627    1.171     2.06
#>  PR    0.922 0.251 627    0.540     1.57
#>  DM    1.944 0.250 627    1.511     2.50
#>  EC-A  1.277 0.246 627    0.875     1.86
#>  EC-L  2.965 0.337 627    2.372     3.71
#>  DES-L 2.844 0.321 627    2.280     3.55
#>  DF    1.626 0.222 627    1.244     2.13
#> 
#> Results are averaged over the levels of: mined 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95 
#> Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale

# ggeffects with emmeans, not taking zero-inflation 
# component into account
ggeffects::ggemmeans(m, "spp", type = "fe")
#> 
#> # Predicted counts of count
#> # x = spp
#> 
#>      x predicted conf.low conf.high
#>     GP     1.553    1.171     2.059
#>     PR     0.922    0.540     1.574
#>     DM     1.944    1.511     2.502
#>   EC-A     1.277    0.875     1.863
#>   EC-L     2.965    2.372     3.707
#>  DES-L     2.844    2.280     3.549
#>     DF     1.626    1.244     2.126

# ggeffects with emmeans, taking zero-inflation 
# component into account
ggeffects::ggemmeans(m, "spp", type = "fe.zi")
#> 
#> # Predicted counts of count
#> # x = spp
#> 
#>      x predicted conf.low conf.high
#>     GP     0.567    0.483     0.651
#>     PR     0.089    0.072     0.107
#>     DM     0.911    0.773     1.048
#>   EC-A     0.204    0.167     0.242
#>   EC-L     1.389    1.172     1.606
#>  DES-L     1.506    1.268     1.744
#>     DF     0.762    0.637     0.886
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It's possible that you need the development version of `glmmTMB` for this?

Comment: I don't think so, I just re-installed glmmTMB 0.2.3 from CRAN and could run the above examples w/o any problems. As far as I can recall, you added emmeans-support for glmmTMB to version 0.2.3 (or even earlier), no?

Answer (score 0):

For count models without zero inflation, `ggeffects::ggpredict(type = "fixed")`, `ggeffects::ggemmeans()`, and `marginaleffects:predictions()`  build confidence intervals of `y = exp(log_mu)` based on normal approximation of `log_mu`. Therefore, CI of y is approximately `exp(log_mu ± 1.96 * SE(log_mu))` which is asymmetrical around mu. This holds true as long as the distributional assumption of response is in the exponential family, which includes Poisson, conventional negative binomial (NB-2), and other negative binomial variants (e.g. NB-1, NB-heterogeneous). Note that the {ggeffects} package gives standard errors on the link scale (log for count models), whereas the {marginaleffects} package gives standard errors on the response scale. The relationship between these two is simple: `SE(response) = ybar * SE(link)`.

The observed mean of a zero-inflated model is a product of two components: a mean structure and a probability of excess zero, each estimated on the link scale, typically giving `ybar = exp(log_mu)*(1 - plogis(log_zi))`. Although `log_mu` and `log_zi` are each assumed to be a liner combination of coefficients with uncertainties following normal distributions, the distribution of `y` as a nonlinear function of these two components are unknown. Therefore, confidence intervals for predicted means in zero-inflated models are usually built via simulation.

I noticed that `ggeffects::ggpredict(type = "fe.zi")` and `marginaleffects:predictions()` are for zero inflated count models are based on a simulation of two separate draws of 1000 random observations for the mean structure and the excess zero probability, respectively, from multivariate normal distributions following Brooks et al. (2017, pp 391-392). Therefore, they vary per run. I have not found ways to control the number of draws in either functions, but setting the seed status using `set.seed()` will generate reproducible results. Somehow the confidence intervals in most cases are symmetrical around the mean in my case study. On the other hand, `ggeffects::ggemmeans()` does not vary per run, which I suspect uses the multivariate delta method. It also produces symmetrical confidence intervals. These three methods give standard errors on the response scale. `ggeffects::ggeffect()` only generate predictions and confidence intervals for the mean structure without considering zero inflation probabilities regardless of the type = argument, and it thus can be misleading.

Brooks, M., E., Kristensen, K., Benthem, K., J. ,van, Magnusson, A., Berg, C., W., Nielsen, A., Skaug, H., J., Mächler, M., & Bolker, B., M. (2017). GlmmTMB balances speed and flexibility among packages for zero-inflated generalized linear mixed modeling. The R Journal, 9(2), 378. https://doi.org/10.32614/RJ-2017-066